# How to truncate string with a regex rule

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I a column of emails that communications went out to (Column A):

```
john.smith@mail.com
john.smith1@mail.com
john.smith2@mail.com
bob.hope@mail.com
jimmy.john@mail.com
jimmy.john2@mail.com
thisguy.didntreply@mail.com
```

And a column of which emails replied (Column B):

```
john.smith1@mail.com
bob.hope.@mail.com
jimmy.john@mail.com
```

I'm using MATCH(A#, B:B, 0) to find which users replied, then filtering by N/A to see the list of users who haven't replied. The problem is, John Smith replied from `john.smith1@mail.com` but his 2 other emails will mark him as someone who didn't reply.

I'd like to use some kind of regex to capture everything before `[0-9]@mail.com`, then be left with a list of 3 `john.smith`'s, then remove duplicates (would do the same for the replied list so a response from `john.smith2` would match.

Ideally I want something like `=LEFT(A#, [0-9]@mail.com)` or even `=LEFT(A#, FIND([0-9], A#))` but I can't put regex in these functions like this. Does anyone have a work around or a better solution? Is there a way I can match this without needing to truncate?

Comment: Are all your emails of the form NAME.NAME@... ?

Comment: Are you sure that `john.smith`, `john.smith1`, and `john.smith2` are the same person? In some instances, they might be three different john smiths.

Comment: And you can use regular expressions.  You just need to create a UDF (user defined function) in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

For a formula that will return *everything before [0-9]@mail.com*, you can try:

```
=LEFT(A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"@"},A1&"0123456789"))-1)
```

The formula assumes that the only digits will be just before the `@`. If that is not the case, the formula would need to be much more complex, and easier done with a VBA UDF.

Of course, in doing this you are assuming that `john.smith`, `john.smith1`, and `john.smith2` are all the same people.

[image]